# Есть ли библиотека для запоминания фильтров в GridView Yii2?

Tags: php, yii2

**Предпосылка:** Пользователи жалуются, что после проведения определенных действий, при возврате на GridView — приходится заново указывать фильтры.

**Цель:**  Хранить выставленные фильтры вплоть до того момента, когда пользователь сам их не сбросит. Это нужно будет сделать только для пару GridView, где жалуются на такую проблему.

Думаю, что не первый, кто столкнулся с проблемой, и вероятно уже есть решение.

Comment: Ну надо знать что это за действия такие... фильты GridView - это GET параметры в URL.